# Search sub folders for symbolic links to a directory?

Tags: bash, debian

In `/var/www` and its subfolders I have symlinks to `/var/src`, spread around in various locations. How can I list all those links?

Comment: Use `find` with `-type l` and `-exec ls -l "{}" \;`, filtering with `grep` if necessary.

Comment: Basically correct (got my vote), just one entry from man find: "-ls    True; list current file in ls -dils format on standard output." That is you don't have to use -exec ls -l here because find with -ls can play its role without calling other processes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments:

```
find /var/www -type l -ls | grep ' /var/www/'
```